# Showing triangle inequality for a metric without using Minkowski's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(E_1,d_1)$ and $(E_2,d_2)$ be metric spaces. Let $E:=E_1\times E_2$ and define
$$d(x,y):=[d_1(x_1,y_1)^2+d_2(x_2,y_2)^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
for all $x=(x_1,x_2)\in E$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)\in E$.

Is it possible to prove $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ without using Minkowski? (Is there a more basic proof?)

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{split}
d(x,z)^2 & = d_1(x_1,z_1)^2 + d_2(x_2,z_2)^2\\
&\le d_1(x_1,y_1)^2  + d_1(y_1,z_1)^2+ d_2(x_2,y_2)^2 +  d_2(y_2,z_2)^2\\
&\le (d_1(x_1,y_1)  + d_1(y_1,z_1))^2+( d_2(x_2,y_2) +  d_2(y_2,z_2))^2\\
\end{split}$$

$$\begin{split}
d(x,z) &\le \sqrt{ (d_1(x_1,y_1)  + d_1(y_1,z_1))^2+( d_2(x_2,y_2) +  d_2(y_2,z_2))^2}\\
&\le  \sqrt{ (d_1(x_1,y_1)  + d_1(y_1,z_1))^2}+\sqrt{( d_2(x_2,y_2) +  d_2(y_2,z_2))^2} \\
&\le  d_1(x_1,y_1)  + d_1(y_1,z_1) +d_2(x_2,y_2) +  d_2(y_2,z_2)
\end{split}$$

This prove uses monotonicity of $x\mapsto x^2$ on nonnegative numbers, and
$a^2+b^2\le (a+b)^2$ implying $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le a+b$.

Comment: Thank you. How to show that $d(x,z)\leq d_1(x_1,y_1)+d_1(y_1,z_1)+d_2(x_2,y_2)+d_2(y_2,z_2)$ implies $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$?

Comment: @Ruan Simply use the fact that $|a|\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ for all $a,b\in\Bbb R$.